# SNMPD reporting conflicting CPU usage to top/htop

Tags: ubuntu, snmp, cpu-usage, top, htop

I've got a bit of an issue with reporting discrepancies.
I've currently got a server running Ubuntu 14.04.1 trusty and am receiving SNMP alerts saying that 2 of my cores are at 100% usage.
When I login to the server to check on this via top/htop it appears as though all cores are under 10% usage.
I can however replicate the SNMP results with a SNMPwalk.
So I've got 2 questions really.

Why the difference in the two?

And how do I confirm which of the two is more accurate?

[htop output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3ZzG.png)

[SNMPwalk output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcgP1.png)

Any insight that anyone can provide into this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both showing the same thing really. The grey bar in the `htop` output signals iowait times, in which the processor is not doing anything  except waiting for IO operations (but is still in use 100%), and I guess it is somehow configured to not use the iowait time for the percentage calculation.

SNMP just gives a broad overview.

Comment: Thanks for this info.
This led me to find the cause of my issue. For anyone who comes here in future looking for an answer to this, here's some extra info.
There were two processes spawned which were using IOwait resources. These were able to be ID'd using 'ps ax | grep D'.

In my case, these were samba processes which were stuck thanks to a bad config option.
Fixed the config, killed the processes, CPU IOwait went down to 0 again.